# fullcalendar not all events are shown in agendaweek view

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using fullcalendar for scheduling system, the problem is events are shown without fail in the month view however, in agendaweek view, only the first event is shown without any problems, but from the second events, there are many issues. 
For example,

```
const events = [
    {
      title  : 'event1',
      start  : '2020-05-12T12:30:00',
      end  : '2020-05-12T14:45:00',
      allDay : false
    },
    {
      title  : 'event2',
      start  : '2020-05-13T14:30:00',
      end  : '2020-05-13T19:30:00',
      allDay : false
    },
    {
        title  : 'event3',
        start  : '2020-05-14T14:30:00',
        end    : '2020-05-14T16:30:00',
        allDay : false
    },
    {
      title  : 'event4',
      start  : '2020-05-15T13:30:00',
      end  : '2020-05-15T15:30:00',
      allDay : false
    }
]
```

[image]

Among those four events, only two events are shown. The event1 is shown perfectly correctly but the second event shown is combination of event2 and event4 event data like below.
The first event's date and time is 5/12 12:30 - 14:45 (all from event1), the second event's date is 5/13 (from event2) time is 13:30 - 15:30 (from event4). And the graphical visualization is also not correct. These two events are only shown agendaweek, not four all events. If anyone has same issue, can you please help me? I spent a lot time on this, but can't find a solution.

I do not see styles for top, bottom for wrong event like the following.
The following is captured from the fullcalendar demo page.

[image]

When it work, if I debug the following code, it shows the following

[image]

But the thing it does not work, it shows the following
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem using standard fullCalendar 4: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/xxwJjEV . As you can see from that demo, all the events show up, no problem. If you have a specific issue, you'll need to show enough of your code so that we could reproduce the issue. I notice your screenshot has an unusual shape for events. Perhaps you have customised the CSS and introduced a problem that way? Try again without any custom CSS and see if you still have the issue. If you still can't fix it, show us the code / make a demo. Thanks

Comment: Yes, we use our own css, but after I revoked all the change we made, tested, but still the same. :(

Comment: you'll need to show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then, because the info you've provided so far doesn't demonstrate the issue. We need enough code, data, CSS etc such that if we ran it, it would show this problem. If you're using fullCalendar 4, you could fork my codepen to start working on your demo. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, will try, the start and end format is right? for example, '2020-05-15T13:30:00'? I am curious the nodejs upgrade has effect on this?

Comment: Fullcalendar is client-side, it has nothing to do with NodeJS (which is server-side). Any yes your date formats are correct - my demo already proves that. The issue is likely to be somewhere in your fullCalendar code, or the related HTML/CSS

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but it's not quite clear to me what you are trying to demonstrate there, or its relevance to the issue. Can you clarify? Also can you please provide the relevant _code_ as requested. Programming problems can rarely be solved without seeing the code.

Comment: @ADyson I still can't figure this out, what I found something is wrong here, https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/3ddb3c8d1461c6b841aed3487ba07d8ba338adb6/dist/fullcalendar.js#L4354

Comment: I use exact same events data, in one environment segs has startMs and endMs while segs has row, firstRowDayIndex, etc... in other environment. I do not have problem displaying events if it has row, firstRowDayIndex, etc.. otherwise, it fails.

Comment: ok so you're using fullCalendar v3, that would have been helpful to know from the beginning. It's an out-of-date version, but still there is no specific issue with it displaying events.

Comment: So let's make a demo using your events, and fullCalendar 3: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGVQKbM?editable=true&editors=001 . It works fine, no problems. It's unclear to me why you are poring over the fullCalendar source code. As we can see from your screenshot, you are using some custom CSS. By far the most likely explanation for your issue is an error in that CSS. That's especially true since my demo proves that the basic fullCalendar code is capable of displaying the events.

Comment: @ADyson, if it does not have problem, it just returns renderedSegs immediately, but if it fails, it jumps to rejectPromise(promise, e);

Comment: Look, for the last time, you're going to have to make a working demo which **actually reproduces this problem**, because I cannot reproduce it, and neither can anyone else, based on the info you've provided so far. And we cannot suggest how to fix a problem that we can't see happening. As I've shown you, fullCalendar will display your sample data correctly. So maybe fork my demo and change it so it actually shows this issue occurring. I will be very surprised if the issue really is within the fullCalendar.js file, though.

Comment: You're talking about "when it works" and "when it doesn't work", but what's completely unclear to me is what the difference between those situations is. What changes, in your environment, to make it stop working? You haven't shown anything which would account for it. that's the information we will need in order to help you.

Comment: @ADyson there is a way we can talk by chatting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214129/discussion-between-adyson-and-anna-lee).